# CampaignMonitor for WooCommerce - Move subscribe button

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

So I need to move the checkbox provided by CampaignMonitor for WooCommerce to a different part of the checkout screen. I've already managed to copy it to the right place via

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', '\core\App::woocommerce_subscription_box' );
```

But I can't remove it from it's original location. Looking at the plugin, it starts with...

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function(){
    // Truncated for brevity
    core\App::run();
});
```

In `core\App::run()` it just initiates the class, and in the constructor is

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', array(__CLASS__, 'woocommerce_subscription_box'));
```

So we know how the action is being added, and I've tried all sorts but nothing works to remove the action from `woocommerce_review_order_after_submit`.

I've tried...

```
// Doesn't work
remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', '\core\App::woocommerce_subscription_box' );

// Doesn't work
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', '\core\App::woocommerce_subscription_box', 11 );
}, 11);
```

Can anyone understand why I can't seem to remove that action?

Comment: Try using an array for the callback name: `remove_action( '...etc.', [ '\core\App', 'woocommerce_subscription_box' ] );`

Comment: @JacobPeattie didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (not hooked to plugins_loaded):

```
remove_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', array('core\App', 'woocommerce_subscription_box'));
```

Note there's also an option in the plugin settings 'Show subscription option at checkout' which will also remove it...